# How do I attach objects to the nodes and edges of a graph using the Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I would like to use the Boost Graph Library more effectively by attaching properly encapsulated classes to graph nodes & edges. I am not interested in attaching int's or POD struct's. Following suggestions on other StackOverFlow articles, I have developed the following sample app. Can anybody tell me the magic I need to sprinkle onto the EdgeInfo class to make this thing compile?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Boost 1.54.0.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <iostream>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct VertexInfo
{
    struct Tag
    {
        typedef boost::vertex_property_tag  kind;
        static  std::size_t const           num; // ???
    };
    typedef boost::property<Tag, VertexInfo>    Property;
};
std::size_t const VertexInfo::Tag::num = reinterpret_cast<std::size_t> (&VertexInfo::Tag::num);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
class EdgeInfo
{
    int     _nWeight;
public:
    int     getWeight () const              {return _nWeight;}
    struct Tag
    {
        typedef boost::edge_property_tag    kind;
        static  std::size_t const           num; // ???
    };
    typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>  Weight;
    typedef boost::property<Tag, EdgeInfo>              Property;
    EdgeInfo (int nWeight = 9999) : _nWeight (nWeight)   {}
};
std::size_t const EdgeInfo::Tag::num = reinterpret_cast<std::size_t> (&EdgeInfo::Tag::num);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>  EdgeProperty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexInfo::Property, EdgeProperty>       GraphWorking;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexInfo::Property, EdgeInfo::Property> GraphBroken;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename GraphType, typename EdgeType> void
dijkstra (GraphType g, EdgeType e)
{
    typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_descriptor   VertexDesc;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_descriptor     EdgeDesc;

    VertexDesc u = add_vertex (g);
    VertexDesc v = add_vertex (g);
    std::pair<EdgeDesc, bool> result = add_edge (u, v, e, g);
    std::vector<VertexDesc> vecParent (num_vertices (g), 0);

    dijkstra_shortest_paths (g, u, boost::predecessor_map (&vecParent[0]));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
#if defined(BOOST_MSVC) && BOOST_MSVC <= 1300
    std::cout   << "Buy a new compiler\n";
#else
    std::cout   << "Your compiler is fine\n";
#endif
    GraphWorking gWorking;
    GraphBroken gBroken;

    dijkstra (gWorking, 3);
    dijkstra (gBroken, EdgeInfo (4));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I admit I'm not motivated to work this out. Have you looked at [Bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html)? They seem a ways easier to use. Also, are you aware of `BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY` which apparently alleviates some of the red-tape involved?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code i get an error in numeric_limits that results from a distance map in dijkstra.

"
Error   1   error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'D' c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\limits   92
"
probably from this part of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp

```
 typedef typename property_traits<DistanceMap>::value_type D;
  D inf = choose_param(get_param(params, distance_inf_t()),
                       (std::numeric_limits<D>::max)());
```

I think there may be an easier way to tie a real class for your nodes and edges. Its more trouble than its worth to create vertex and edge property classes that will provide all the needed tagged properties (index, weight, color, etc) needed for most boost algorihtms.

Don't forget Edge class != Edge property.

The edge class is really the graph_traits::edge_discriptor.

Properties are the data associated with each edge. Same for vertex.

I would use bundled properties and add a pointer to your class in each one.

Here is an example

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

//Fancy Edge class
class EdgeData
{
    int _data;
public:
    EdgeData(){
        _data=0;
    }

    EdgeData(int data){
        _data= data;
    }

    void printHello(){
        std::cout << "hello " << _data << std::endl;
    }


};


//Fancy Vert class
class VertexData
{
    int _data;
public:
    VertexData(){
        _data=0;
    }

    VertexData(int data){
        _data= data;
    }

    void printHello(){
        std::cout << "hello " << _data << std::endl;
    }


};

//bundled properties
struct VertexProps
{
    VertexData* data;
};

struct EdgeProps
{
    size_t weight;
    EdgeData* data;
};


//Graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    VertexProps,EdgeProps> Graph;

//helpers
//Vertex
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex; 
//Edge
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename GraphType> void
  templateFunction (GraphType g)
{
    typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_iterator edge_iter;
    std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> ep;
    edge_iter ei, ei_end;
    ep = edges(g);
    ei_end = ep.second;

    for (ei = ep.first; ei != ei_end; ++ei){
        g[*ei].data->printHello();
    }

}

//if you want to alter the graph use referenced &graph
template<typename GraphType,typename EdgePropType> void
  templateFuctionProps(GraphType &g, EdgePropType e)
{
    typedef boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::vertex_descriptor   VertexDesc;

    VertexDesc v = add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc u = add_vertex(g);

    //add an edge with the Edge property
    add_edge(v,u,e,g);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    Graph g;

    //vertex holder
    std::vector<Vertex> verts;

    //add some verts
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        Vertex v = add_vertex(g);
        g[v].data = new VertexData(i%2);
        verts.push_back(v);
    }

    //add some edges
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        std::pair<Edge,bool> p = add_edge(verts.at(i),verts.at(i+1),g);
        Edge e = p.first;
        g[e].data = new EdgeData(i%3);
        g[e].weight = 5;
    }

    //iterate edges and call a class function
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_iter;
    std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> ep;
    edge_iter ei, ei_end;
    ep = edges(g);
    ei_end = ep.second;
    for (ei = ep.first; ei != ei_end; ++ei){
        g[*ei].data->printHello();
    }


    std::cout << "Iterate with template with template " << std::endl;
    templateFunction(g);


    //Use an edge property in a function
    EdgeProps edgeProp;
    edgeProp.weight = 5;
    edgeProp.data = new EdgeData(150);
    std::cout << "Modity graph with template function " << std::endl;
    templateFuctionProps(g,edgeProp);

    std::cout << "Iterate again with template" << std::endl;
    templateFunction(g);

    //getting the weight property
    boost::property_map<Graph,size_t EdgeProps::*>::type w
        = get(&EdgeProps::weight, g);


    std::cout << "Print weights" << std::endl;
    ep = edges(g);
    ei_end = ep.second;
    for (ei = ep.first; ei != ei_end; ++ei){
        std::cout << w[*ei] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also I see you are using vecS, meaning that both vectors and edges are stored as vectors with a fixed ordering.

You could just have a class that stores your Edge and Vertex classes with a pointer to the vertex map or edge map for the graph.

I don't know your goals for this project, but I would definitely have higher level classes than manage all of this boost stuff behind the scenes. Meaning storing classes in a vector with an index look up would be hidden and encapsulated from applications that want to use your nice graph class.